# Perl merge hashes

Tags: perl, hash, hashref

Is it possible to merge two hashes like so:

```
%one = {
    name    => 'a',
    address => 'b'
};

%two = {
    testval => 'hello',
    newval  => 'bye'        
};

$one{location} = %two;
```

so the end hash looks like this:

```
%one = {
    name    => 'a',
    address => 'b',
    location => {
        testval => 'hello',
        newval  => 'bye'
    }
}
```

I've had a look but unsure if this can be done without a for loop. Thanks :)

Comment: `%hash = { key => value }` syntax is wrong (do you `use warnings`?). `{ ... }` defines a *hash reference*. You either want to say `%hash = ( key => value , ... )` or `$hashref = { key => value, ... }`

Comment: Your outer {}s should be ()s. () makes hash, {} makes hash ref.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can't store a hash in a hash since the values of hash elements are scalars, but one can store a *reference* to a hash. (Same goes for storing arrays and storing into arrays.)

```
my %one = (
   name    => 'a',
   address => 'b',
);

my %two = (
   testval => 'hello',
   newval  => 'bye',     
);

$one{location} = \%two;
```

is the same as

```
my %one = (
   name    => 'a',
   address => 'b',
   location => {
      testval => 'hello',
      newval  => 'bye',
   },
);
```

Comment: should that say *aren't scalars*?

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, No. Like  I said, they *are* scalars, which is why you can't store hash or array in them.

Comment: The wording before threw me off, I see what you meant now.

Answer (score 3):

If you use

```
$one{location} = \%two
```

then your hash will contain a *reference* to hash `%two`, so that if you modify it with something like `$one{location}{newval} = 'goodbye'` then `%two` will also be changed.

If you want a *separate copy* of the data in `%two` then you need to write

```
$one{location} = { %two }
```

after which the contents of `%one` are independent of `%two` and can be modified separately.

Comment: `{ %two }` is rarely needed as the proper placement of `my %two;` will normally handle creating a new hash when needed.